# Removing all borders from HTML table

Tags: html, html-table, border

I've tried everything I can find so far in other stack overflow questions to solve this issue but can't get it figured out.  I've got an HTML table with background images that I'm using to create rounded dividers/bubbles around specific items on a website.  I can't get the table rows to completely go away though.  And it seems like they are only to top and right that are showing a division?  Both CSS and the table are shown below.  Here's an image of what I can't get rid of.  You can see the thin line right under the curves down then along the right side of the right border.  It shows up other places too but the background is so close to the border color that it's not noticeable.

Also there is some redundant CSS in there I've just been trying everything I can find/think of in order to fix is.

I can't add images but here's a link with the image of the result I keep getting http://www.bdtransport.com/devel/TableIssue.JPG

Code:

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 border: none !important;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
tr, td {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
 spacing: 0
 border: none !important;
 outline: none;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<TABLE width='1100' align='center'>
  <TR>
   <TD colspan='5' background='./images/MainTop.jpg'>&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD background='./images/MainLeft.jpg' width='75'> &nbsp; </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNewsBackground.jpg' width='687'> Text </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNewsDivider.jpg' width='22'> &nbsp; </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNotificationsBackground.jpg' width='250'> Recent/Upcoming Info: </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainRight.jpg' width='66'> &nbsp; </TD>
  </TR>
 </table>
```

Comment: The snippet's not showing any borders on your table cells.  Maybe supply absolute paths on the images for better reproduction?

Comment: You can try <table border="0">

Comment: Absolute paths still produced the same result.  I started out with <TABLE border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> because that's what I historically used (it's been a little while since I have done html work like this) and it didn't work.  That's when I started working with all the CSS above.

Comment: Tables don’t have borders by default. Either your real page has some CSS that causes some borders, or you are misinterpreting something as table border.

Comment: It couldn't just be a line between each row instead of a border?  I've got background images I want to butt completely up to each other with no space at all between them.

Comment: I had a similar issue where additional CSS was causing the problem. I found these were caused/fixed my problem in a web app with many layers of CSS: `border-top-width: 0px;` and `border-right-width:0px;` and `line-height: 0;`. Suggest opening up F12 Developer Tools in IE or Chrome or Firefox and start looking through the CSS styles being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following code snippet has been edited to include border="0" in the table opening. This should remove all borders.

```html
<TABLE width='1100' align='center' border="0">
  <TR>
   <TD colspan='5' background='./images/MainTop.jpg'>&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD background='./images/MainLeft.jpg' width='75'> &nbsp; </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNewsBackground.jpg' width='687'> Text </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNewsDivider.jpg' width='22'> &nbsp; </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNotificationsBackground.jpg' width='250'> Recent/Upcoming Info: </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainRight.jpg' width='66'> &nbsp; </TD>
  </TR>
 </table>
```

If that did not remove all borders, you can try:

```html
<TABLE width='1100' align='center' style="border:0">
  <TR>
   <TD colspan='5' background='./images/MainTop.jpg'>&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD background='./images/MainLeft.jpg' width='75'> &nbsp; </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNewsBackground.jpg' width='687'> Text </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNewsDivider.jpg' width='22'> &nbsp; </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainNotificationsBackground.jpg' width='250'> Recent/Upcoming Info: </TD>
   <TD background='./images/MainRight.jpg' width='66'> &nbsp; </TD>
  </TR>
 </table>
```

That should remove the border. With this method, there is also no need for overly complicated CSS code in your page.